# TCP client server not receiving any data from each other

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-sockets

I have written the following TCP client and server using python socket module. However, after I run them, no output is being given. It seems that 
the program is not able to come out of the while loop in the recv_all method
Server:

```
import socket


def recv_all(sock):
    data = []
    while True:
        dat = sock.recv(18)
        if not dat:
            break
        data.append(dat)

    return "".join(data)


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 45678
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(1)
print "listening at", sock.getsockname()
while True:
    s, addr = sock.accept()
    print "receiving from", addr
    final = recv_all(s)
    print "the client sent", final
    s.sendall("hello client")
    s.close()
```

Client :

```
import socket


def recv_all(sock):
    data=[]
    while True:
        dat=sock.recv(18)
        if not dat:
            break
        data.append(dat)
    return "".join(data)

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
PORT=45678
HOST='127.0.0.1'
sock.connect((HOST,PORT))
sock.sendall("hi server")

final=recv_all(sock)

print "the server sent",final
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in server file you use an endless loop in another. I suggest you to edit `recv_all` method in both files this way:

```
def recv_all(sock):
data = []
dat = sock.recv(18)
data.append(dat)
return "".join(data)
```

But after edit like this your server stays on until `KeyInterrupt`, while you should run client file everytime you want to send data. If you want an automatically `send/receive` between server and client, I offer you try `threading`.

Comment: shouldn't the server recvall method break, when it stops receiving data ?